# How to export a single Java Class with its dependencies using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to export a Java class so it can be used by other programmers. Does Eclipse offer a way to export a class along with all its dependencies maintaining the original package structure? The idea is to export a ready to use project with source code that can be easily used by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark , in eclipse you can export as a ZIP . Other developers can then import the source as-is from the ZIP/TAR

FILE -> EXPORT

[image]

Enter the ZIP file name
Click Finish.